# Python TypeError - MySQL executemany

Tags: python, mysql

I am using the MySQLdb module to insert into my database. I have the following code

```
      sqlString = """INSERT INTO PERFORMER (PERFORMER)
                     VALUES (%s)
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PERFORMER P
                                       WHERE P.PERFORMER = %s)"""
      data = [(c, c) for c in self._performers]
      self._cursor.executemany(sqlString, data)
```

Basically I want to insert entries from `self._performers` (this is just a list of names) that aren't already in the `PERFORMERS` table. But I'm getting the following TypeError

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Full trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tvGuide.py", line 437, in <module>
        processing.UpdatePerformers()
File "tvGuide.py", line 307, in UpdatePerformers
        self._cursor.executemany(sqlString, data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 246, in executemany
        self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, msg)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The self._performers list is very long, but here's a sample of the first few entries

```
['Lucy Alexander', 'Martin Roberts', 'Alistair Appleton', 'Zak Bagans', 'Aaron Goodwin', 'Nick Groff', 'John Zaffis', 'Ellen Pompeo', 'Patrick Dempsey',
```

Comment: Could we please have the **full traceback**? It helps to better localise the source of the error.

Comment: @AlexThornton sorry, I've added it now

Comment: Can you print the contents of `self._performers`?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I would add it here, but the list of names is in excess of 18k

Comment: First few is fine. Is there any possibility any items aren't strings? (I doubt that would explain it, though)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I did think of that, but to be sure I str everything before appending it to the list, still get the TypeError.

Comment: My SQL knowledge might be a little rusty, but are you allowed to put a WHERE clause into an insert statement like that? Doesn't it need to be inside of a SELECT clause?

Looking at this as reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html
Maybe MySQLdb is doing something when it encounters an unexpected WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to Nacho, the TypeError was somewhat of a redherring, it's illegal to use a WHERE with the VALUES clause.